# Vector Drawables in Compose Preview

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-preview

Simple scenario,

I have a vector drawable in my res folder, which I wish to access in a Compose Preview. Actually, it is a `Canvas` that draws the vector, and so, I use a painter (a vector painter, to be precise). This is the method used

```
    @Preview
    @Composable
    fun PreviewTesting() {
        val painter = rememberVectorPainter(image = ImageVector.vectorResource(id = R.drawable.example))
        Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
            with(painter) {
                 draw(Size(100f, 100f))
            }
        }
    }
```

This produces a `ResourceNotFoundException` in the Preview Tab, under the category of a 'Render Problem'. The logs are as follows:

```
It worked somehow now, without any efforts whatsoever, but the logs included something close to ResourceFoundException : Cannot find the resource(0xFFVscjiwoxxxxx)
```

The second method I tried was

```
rememberVectorPainter(image = ImageVector.vectorResource(theme = null, res = resources, id = R.drawable.example))
```

This produces these logs (error-ful)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:100)
    at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResourcesInternal(ContextThemeWrapper.java:134)
    at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:128)
    at com.gmarsk.aiare.MainActivity.AlarmsCreationScreen(MainActivity.kt:1716)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.CommonPreviewUtils.invokeComposableMethod(CommonPreviewUtils.kt:150)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.CommonPreviewUtils.invokeComposableViaReflection$ui_tooling_release(CommonPreviewUtils.kt:194)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1$composable$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:597)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1$composable$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:595)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:634)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:590)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.InspectableKt.Inspectable(Inspectable.kt:61)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$WrapPreview$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:539)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$WrapPreview$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:538)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter.WrapPreview(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:533)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter.access$WrapPreview(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:123)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:590)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:587)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView.Content(ComposeView.android.kt:402)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:248)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:247)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt.ProvideCommonCompositionLocals(CompositionLocals.kt:177)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:123)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:122)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt.ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:114)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:157)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:156)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:156)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:140)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ActualJvm_jvmKt.invokeComposable(ActualJvm.jvm.kt:74)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:3164)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:3154)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:252)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(Unknown Source)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:3154)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.composeContent$runtime_release(Composer.kt:3091)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeContent(Composition.kt:568)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:811)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:503)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:140)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:131)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.setOnViewTreeOwnersAvailable(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:998)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.setContent(Wrapper.android.kt:131)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.onStateChanged(Wrapper.android.kt:182)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:360)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:202)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:138)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:131)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onAttachedToWindow(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1085)
    at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:20753)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3490)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3497)
    at android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:58)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:366)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:436)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:121)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:715)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$9(RenderTask.java:871)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$2.run(RenderExecutor.kt:187)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```